# Using DBpedia to find which Wikipedia categories are common to several given pages?

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I've forgotten all I once new about DBpedia and `SPARQL` and find all the examples too complex and hard to understand when I Google for them.

What I wish to do is pass in two or three Wikipedia pages and get back the set of Wikipedia categories that all of the pages are members of.

This seems that it should be utterly simple in `SPARQL` so I would appreciate a very minimal example to get me started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a variation of your earlier question about [getting all pages belonging to two categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292152/how-to-find-all-wikipedia-pages-which-are-members-two-given-categories-using-dbp). The only difference is that this time, you want two/three *subjects* rather than *objects*, so you cannot use a comma-separated enumeration of values, but instead have to write out the triple pattern that you want to match.

For example, to get back all categories that both Spain and Portugal belong to, you could simply do a query like this:

```
SELECT ?cat   
WHERE { 
 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Spain> dcterms:subject ?cat .
 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Portugal> dcterms:subject ?cat .
}
```

what this query does is select all triple patterns that have the same value of `?cat` for the `dcterms:subject` relation for the subjects 'Spain' and 'Portugal'. In other words, it retrieves precisely those categories that both resources are a member of.

The trick is to think in terms of a graph, or triples with connected subjects and objects. It's a bit of a mental shift but once you've got that, query writing becomes a lot easier.

Comment: Aha this both looks simpler than William's answer and your explanations are also very clear so you get the cookie - thanks (-:

Answer (score 1):

The mapping between wikipedia and dbpedia URI's is as follows:

For

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spain

DBPedia uri is:

http://dbpedia.org/resource/Spain

So to find out the categories for the above

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?categoryUri ?categoryName
WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Spain> dcterms:subject ?categoryUri.
  ?categoryUri rdfs:label ?categoryName.
  FILTER (lang(?categoryName) = "en")
}
```

Comment: This is helpful but I'm still at a loss how to get from this to "Which categories are in all of the pages: page ABC, page DEF, and page XYZ. Maybe my question wasn't very clear?

Comment: Actually it seems just duplicating the line `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Spain> dcterms:subject ?categoryUri.` with something else taking the place of `Spain` does what I want, though I don't really understand the syntax and thus why it works (-: